# macro/vba copy corresponding rows into the corresponding workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a row into multiple worksheets.

In managing employee work products, I want the name of the employees (column A) and their info (column B,C,D,E,F, and G) to go to a corresponding worksheet for each employee.

Ideally, the first 'tab' is all the info. Worksheet 2 would be Employee 2 with the row of info auto populating and so on and so forth.

The code I've attempted only does one row.

Comment: Show your code so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: I'm assuming this is for Excel?

Comment: Sounds like a database. This would be much easier to do in Access...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do this.  Having multiple sheets that contain just one row just seems like a waste.
Anyways this isn't auto updating, run it multiple times and you will get multiple pages for each employee.  If you want more functionality you should provide more info as what you want.  That code you mentioned that you wrote you should share.

```
Const EMPLOYEE_NAME_COL As String = "A"
Const LAST_COL As String = "G"
Const MY_BOOK_NAME As String = "name your workbook"
Const INFO_SHEET_INDEX As Integer = 1

Function GetNewSheetAtEnd(book As Workbook) As Worksheet

    Dim sheets as Collection
    Set sheets = book.sheets

    Set GetNewSheetAtEnd = sheets.add(after:=sheets(sheets.count))

End Function

' Modify this Sub to copy however you want it to
Sub CopyRangeToSheet(rng As Range, sheet As WorkSheet)

    rng.Copy sheet.Range("A1")

End Sub

Sub CopyEmployeesToNewSheets()

    Dim info_sheet as Worksheet
    Set info_sheet = Workbooks(MY_BOOK_NAME).Sheets(INFO_SHEET_INDEX)

    Dim employees_range As Range
    ' Assumes you have a header.  You will probably need to modify this.
    Set employees_range = info_sheet.Range("A2:G" & info_sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

    Dim employee_row As Range
    For Each employee_row In employees_range.Rows

        CopyRangeToSheet employee_row, GetNewSheetAtEnd()

    Next employee_row

End Sub
```